# Javascript to open an actual window

Tags: javascript, html, animation, gif

I am trying to make an animation using javascript.

Basically, there will be a window on a wall, and when the mouse hovers over, the window will open up, and an image will show.

I know this is really specific, but can someone good at javascript help me with it?

My thought on it is to create a `gif` that does the opening animation, and use javascript to control the timing.

What do you think?

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com We are volunteers who want to help you with a specific problem. We donate our time; donate some of yours and show that you at least tried **something**

Answer (score 0):

Make a div and position it absolute so that this div will represent your window. Then make a function that represent an animation. Each time when it is called the function should make a tiny change to position and size of "window". Call this function at regular intervals with setTimeout and you will achieve animation. If mouse goes out you have to start rollback animation. Read a little bit more about JS times and u will write it.

Also as advice always white times like this:

```
setTimeout(func() {
    ....
}, 1000);
```

In this case func() will be called after 1000ms. So you can add this timer at the end of your function. Make your function to be called from func() and you will have the loop.

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help but I created a website with a similar function for opening doors with the mouse hover.  The website is http://www.bandofamericasfew.com/  Go view the source and see if it helps. If you have any questions then let me know.